# What is Azure functions Cron Expression to trigger on 2nd Sunday of every month?

Tags: cron, azure-functions, crontrigger

I have Timer Trigger Azure function, which I want to trigger on 2nd Sunday of every month. what should be the cron expression for it?

I have tried below ones but it's showing as wrong format of cron expression

0 0 0 ? * 7#2
0 0 0 ? * SUN#2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second Sunday of the month falls on one (and only one) of the dates from the 8th to the 14th inclusive. Then the cron expression will be easy to get it.

Suppose it should be `0 0 0 8-14 * Sun` and the below is my test, it shows the first five date.

[image]

From the picture suppose the expression should be right, hope this could help you.

Comment: If this could help you, you could [accept it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).